# How to know the lastchunk from server side using blueimp jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, azure, azure-storage, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

In [Jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) We can upload large files in Chunks using **maxChunkSize**.It works fine there are multiple request for each chunk.How can we know the if the chunk send is lastchunk.Is there an value present in Request for this to be determined?

**Practical Scnerio :**
We are using Windows Azure storing a large file in Azure blob. So for uploading a large file we are sending chunk by chunk from file-uploader. The problem is we cannot determine when is the last chunk coming. So that we can commit the blob after all chunk has been successfully received.

Alternative to above problem,Is there a way in Azure in which we can keep on adding the chunks to blob as we receive the chunk bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [`chunksend` callback?](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-chunksend)

```
chunksend: function (e, data) {
    if((data.uploadedBytes + data.chunkSize ) == data.total)
        // Notice the server that this is the last packet, with the formData option maybe
},
```

But be careful, the `data.uploadedBytes` value can be quite surprising, I've open an issue ticket about it.